# Does the Microsoft WebDriver work on Windows Insider builds?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, microsoft-webdriver

I am trying to get started with the [Microsoft Web Driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). It appears you have to download a specific driver for a particular release of Windows 10. Does anyone know if the latest driver will work with Windows Insider builds or do I have to run and develop on a more stock version of windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very page you linked to, there is a link for a version for Insider "fast ring" builds. It is usually kept current for the most current build. I've only seen a few occasions that the executable under that link does not work with the latest Insider build, and on every occasion I've seen that, the driver has been updated pretty quickly (within a couple of days) with a fix. So, yes, the latest driver will, in general, work with the latest Insider builds.

Comment: I got tripped up looking for the insider build number (16125) . the insider link is oddly positioned in the list. my brain just fused all the build numbers together and when I couldn't find the fast ring # I was looking for concluded it wasn't there.